# Can I pass an array of lambda expressions to a method with a params argument?

Tags: c#, lambda, parameters, expression

I want to call a method like this:

signature: `void Method(object a, object b, params LambdaExpression[] expressions);`

call: `Method(a, b, x => x.A, x => x.B)`

Is it possible?

Let's assume that the type of 'x' is a constant type.  For example, if x => x.A and y => y.B were Funcs, they'd be `Func<TType,*>`, such that the params array always had the same type for `TType`, but the return value's type `*` could differ from element to element of the params array.  That's why I had to choose something more generic like LambdaExpression as the type, but I don't know if that will work.  I can unpack the expression within the method at runtime, but I'm having a hard time just trying to pass expressions to a method when one of their two generic type parameters differ.

It would be fine, even if I had to call it more like: `Method(a, b, (Type x) => x.A, (Type x) => x.B)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can but the compiler assist that will turn your code to expression(vs compiling it) works with generics only. So you have to

```
Expression<Func<TType, AType>> expr1 = x => x.A;
Expression<Func<TType, BType>> expr2 = x => x.B;

Method(a, b, expr1, expr2);
```

or cast inline

```
Method(a, b, (Expression<Func<TType, AType>>) (x => x.A), expr2)
```

or use a more generic type of argument

```
void Method(object a, object b, params Expression<Func<object, object>>[] expressions)
```

Comment: So basically the answer is no.  I have to specify the types at compile time.

Comment: yes, but you only use readability/more typing - you already know the types of the expressions at compile time.
If you want to avoid the cast you can use more generic argument type - see update.

Comment: That last one is the solution for this, because it allows you to call a method such as `void Method<T>(params Expression<Func<T,object>> expressions)` like this: `Method<Car>(x => x.Wheel, x => w.Door)` without requiring any explicit casting.  The compiler is able to create an expression from `x => x.Wheel` because the type is `Expression<Func<,>>`.  Furthermore, the expression can actually be converted to a stronger type like `Expression<Func<Car,Door>>` at runtime using reflection and a call to `Expression.Lambda`, but that's beyond the scope of this question.  Thanks.

Comment: See also my follow up question: http://stackoverflow.com/q/43815289/88409