# Is it possible to convert a lambda expression of some return type to its equivalent expression of a more specific type?

Tags: c#, lambda, expression-trees

```
public class Entity
{
    public int A { get; set; }
    public string B { get; set; }
}

Expression<Func<Entity,object>> expr = x => x.A;
Expression<Func<Entity,int>> exprAtRuntime = x => x.A;

Expression<Func<Entity,object>> expr2 = x => x.B;
Expression<Func<Entity,string>> expr2AtRuntime = x => x.B;
```

How can I take `expr` and convert it to the type of `expr2` at runtime?

Likewise, I need to do the same for property B. I need to accept a params array of type `Expression<Func<Entity,object>>` which represents accessing different properties of an object, so they all need to have the Entity type and the general return type of object (as [answered in this precursor question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43814982/88409)).

But from that expression, I need to construct it's more strongly-typed version for each element of the params array (i.e. convert `Expression<Func<TEntity,object>>` to a type specific to the underlying property being accessed `Expression<Func<TEntity,TProperty>>`, using information about the type of the property being accessed on the entity type. How can this be done?

Comment: Why do you need to convert at runtime? In both cases you can assign the expressions to LambdaExpression, compile, invoke - and then exprect the type of the returned object(at runtime).

Comment: Because I don't need to compile or invoke them: I need to *pass* them to a method with the following signature: `public PrimitivePropertyConfiguration Property<T>(Expression<Func<TStructuralType, T>> propertyExpression) where T : struct`  I can do that at runtime through reflection once I get the LambdaExpression (the base type), but only if the inherited type is correct (i.e. `Expression<Func<T,CorrectType>>`).  I'll have to get that `Property` method's MethodInfo, call MakeGenericType on it to get the concrete type to call, then pass it a correctly typed expression for it to work.

Comment: I'm trying to modify the fluent API in entity framework for adding a multi-column index.  I'm on the verge of a solution that will reduce what's currently 20 lines of code down to a single statement that's a lot easier to read and use.

Comment: The trick is that the compiler automatically adds the Convert to object call, so I can use plain properties like `x.B` when writing and passing the expressions.  I basically need to reverse that operation at runtime, removing the wrapping `Convert` call and exposing what the expression would have been without it. I can also grab the member's original type in the process to make the generic method call.

Comment: Why are you constructing them in the first place as `Expression<Func<Entity, object>>` rather than creating them with the correct type?

Comment: While `Func<in T, out TResult>` is a delegate type which is covariant (`out`) in `TResult` (but not contravariant in that second argument, of course), the `Expression<TDelegate>` is a ___class___ type, and no variance in `TDelegate` is possible. This is just to say you cannot hope to solve it with just a reference conversion (cast). So if you must do this transformation, simply use the usual methods (static methods on non-generic [class `Expression`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.expressions.expression.aspx)) to construct a _new_ expression tree from the old one.

Comment: Also, I should mention that Property method actually has several overloads, so I had to do some runtime binding.  There are two generic overloads that are for nullable and non-nullable unsigned primitive value types, respectively.  There are specific non-generic overloads for value types Decimal, DateTime, DateTimeOffset and TimeSpan (and their nullable counterparts).  Finally, there are overloads for reference types DbGeometry, DbGeography, byte[], and string. Nothing else is valid as an entity column type.  It was simple to write the exact logic necessary to choose the correct overload.

Comment: See also, my precursor question to this question: http://stackoverflow.com/q/43814829/88409

Comment: @Rob, because I said "I need to accept a params array", so they all have to be the same type (i.e. the same Expression<T>, and T has to be a Func<,> for the compiler to make it an Expression).  It can't be a LambaExpression, it has to be an Expression<Func<,>> in order for the compiler to turn it into an expression, so the answer is posted below... I have to use a more general return type like object, but it still needs to be an Expression<Func<T,object>> and the ALL have to have that type for it to be used as a params array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To do this, you can use an `ExpressionVisitor` that removes the `Convert` (if it exists) and then fixes up the delegate type:

```
class RemoveConvertVisitor : ExpressionVisitor
{
    protected override Expression VisitUnary(UnaryExpression node) =>
        node.NodeType == ExpressionType.Convert ? node.Operand : base.VisitUnary(node);

    protected override Expression VisitLambda<T>(Expression<T> node) =>
        Expression.Lambda(Visit(node.Body), node.Parameters);
}
```

Comment: So I'd call VisitLambda, which would call visit on the Body, and since Body is a UnaryExpression it would enter the VisitUnary overload and return the Operand of the Convert expression instead of the Convert expression itself (and would otherwise call the base implementation which would return the unmodified value).  The real reason this is possible is because the MemberExpression retains the original property type of the property it's accessing, so even though the return type is "object", the original type of that property is still embedded in the expression tree.

Comment: Incidentally, with this knowledge, I was able to avoid this whole process and just pass an expression like `x => new {x.A, x.B, x.C}` which turns out to still be of type `Expression<Func<T,object>>`, but is a single value instead of an array. From that, I was able to grab the individual member access expressions in order and plug them into a lambda of the appropriate type. Now I can create a multi-column index simply as `modelBuilder.Entity<SomeEntity>.HasIndex("Name", isUnique, isClustered, m => new {m.C1, m.C2, m.C3})`, with optional bools that specify whether it's unique and/or clustered.

Comment: It's also ridiculous that EF still doesn't support creation of indexes with include columns.  What's the point of even modeling index creation if you can't create them the right way to cover a query.  It's not like it's DBA rocket science, you just specify extra non-key columns.

Comment: @Triynko Incidentally or not, you found the better way, which also is consistent with `HasKey` API :)